# Dot operator vs scope resolution operator with modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

How come I can say

```
Math.sqrt(4)
```

or

```
Math::sqrt(4)
```

but I can't say

```
Math.PI
```

in ruby

What is the difference between what the dot operator is doing and the colon operator in this case?

Comment: @alfasin As you already linked to good post,I thought I should write..But now thinking don't need to write...May I use this link to my answer.. ? :)

Comment: @Babai sure thing - as long as you provide the link that you used.

Answer (score 7):

`.` is message passing operator and `::` is scope resolution operator in Ruby. see the below example:

```
module Foo
 X = 12
 def self.bar
   p "hi"
 end
end
Foo::bar # => "hi"
Foo.bar  # => "hi"
Foo::X # => 12
Foo.X
# undefined method `X' for Foo:Module (NoMethodError)
```

In Ruby you can call class or module methods(which can be called by the class/module name itself) like `bar` using the `.` and `::` also. But the constants like `X` should need to be called using `::`,but `.` is not allowed.In your case `sqrt` is a class method of the module `Math`,whereas `PI` is a constant of the module `Math`.